# Are there any MySQL tools available for modifying Stored Procedures using GUI (not manually by writing code)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

I want to know that is there MYSQL Tool available in which we can modify the existing Stored Procedures by using GUI. I do not want to write code manually in the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(My)SQL is a scripting language (well, actually a query language, but for the purpose of this answer that comes pretty close). It's all about writing text to create commands/queries. How can this be done using a GUI (other than providing a text editor)? I have seen visual query builders in the past and they all suffer from the language's complexity. Most of the time it's easier to see the written text than a graphical view of the query. And as soon as you enter the world of non-trivial queries such query builders will be lost.

So, there's a reason that serious visual query builders are pretty uncommon among the popular MySQL GUI tools.